# PHP date_diff not considering the year

Tags: php, datediff

I'm running the piece of code below expecting the difference in month to be `12`, but instead I'm getting `0`. And reading the manuals I can't find a way to do so.

```
    $from = date_create_from_format('m/d/Y', '01/01/2017');
    $to = date_create_from_format('m/d/Y', '01/01/2018');
    die(date_diff($from, $to)->format('%m'));
```

The result is right, but not considering the year. Is there any extra parameter I should add for the `date_diff` to consider the year?

Comment: If I recall correctly, PHP's `DateTime` will reduce time to the largest units for date diffs. Using `%m` will return 0 as the 12 months are reduced to 1 year. [Example](https://ideone.com/rGoN6q)

Comment: I had a similar strange behaviour while trying to subtract the interval of 1 month from a date (e.g. 28th of february) which returned me not the 1th of the previous month. This behaviour seems to be the "correct" way even if it is far from what normally will be expected. My solution was to write my own class for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because DateInterval::format() does not recalculate carry over points in time strings nor in date segments, you can do the following instead, by multiplying the year by 12 months, and adding any remaining months:

```
$from = date_create_from_format('m/d/Y', '01/01/2017');
$to = date_create_from_format('m/d/Y', '01/01/2018');
$interval = date_diff($from, $to);
echo $interval->m + 12*$interval->y; // 12
```

Example: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/628292d8d0f1ea00e2086b3de059c2e913b1af7d

> The DateInterval::format() method does not recalculate carry over points in time strings nor in date segments. This is expected because it is not possible to overflow values like "32 days" which could be interpreted as anything from "1 month and 4 days" to "1 month and 1 day".
>   http://php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.format.php

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I did this as well, but I thought there was something in the function that I wasn't aware of.